# jQuery UI Dialog button appears hidden and disabled

Tags: jquery, dialog, hidden

I think I'll became mad today.

I'm trying to create a confirm msg when you click a button (in fact an a link) with jQuery UI Dialog.

I'm including jquery-1.6.min.js, jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js and jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css with its images. I create a theme in jquery and add this files to my code. The only reason we are still using jquery 1.6 is due to we have some old js libraries and the update will require some time replacing deprecated methods and we cannot allow us to do that at this time.

I've noticed that the buttons are generated but in the following form:

```
<button type="button" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">OK</button>
<button type="button" style="display: none;" disabled="disabled">Cancel</button>
```

Reading some posts the conclution was some incompatibility or issue with js and css files.
So I worried about my old jquery version and tried my code in JsFiddle and SURPRISE! It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/ndlascano/SNYwd/7/

pd: in the code you'll see callbacks on buttons, if I manually enable the buttons and make  them visible, all is working ok.

Comment: There is not enough information to look into this issue.

Comment: Mmm this could help?

Things I've tried:
Adding buttons like this:
    - buttons : {text:function},{secondtext:secondfunction},...
    - buttons: [ { text: "close" } ]
});
Some people suggest with autoOpen:true. I tried both: true, false.
Inizializing the dialog at first of my script in ready area and calling this later and as a function.

Comment: Now i've disabled those js files that didnt allow me to use a newer version of jquery and i've tried with 1.9.1.min.js but still facing same issue.